# Invalid conversion error on returning a pointer to instance of a derived class using function defined in the base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

This may be a trivial question, but I am trying to re-acquaint myself with C++ and can't find a solution here.  So I would appreciate any help.

Consider the following implementation of an element in a linked list:

```
class Item {
 public:
  void set_val(int val) { val_=val; }
  int get_val() const { return val_; }
  void set_next(Item* next) { next_=next; }
  Item* get_next() const { return next_; }
 private:
  int val_;
  Item* next_
}
```

Now consider deriving the following class from it:

```
class NewItem: public Item {
 public:
  void set_newval(int val) { newval_=val; }
  int get_newval() const { return newval_; }
 private:
  int newval_;
}
```

Basically, the derived class adds another value.  Let's instantiate the following objects:

```
NewItem* i1 = new NewItem;
NewItem* i2 = new NewItem;
i1->set_next(i2);
```

This works without any errors.  I can also access both val and newval. However, the following line

```
NewItem* i3;
i3=i1->get_next();
```

produces an error

```
testprogram.cc:24:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘Item*’ to ‘NewItem*’ [-fpermissive]
```

I understand that the `get_next()`  method is returning a pointer to the base class.  Is there any way to fix my problem?  Perhaps I should re-structure my class declarations?  Adding a "next" pointer for every new derived class seems wasteful.  Re-casting seems dangerous.  Is there a more elegant solution??

Comment: How can you be sure that `get_next()` does actually return a `NewItem` pointer? Nothing's stopping me from calling `set_next` passing any odd class derived from `Item`.

Comment: If you set up a class to represent a list of `Item *`, then you should access them through the `Item *` interface. Using `NewItem *` pointers directly seems to defeat the purpose of setting the list up that way. This seems to be largely just a bad OOP design. Templates may be better than inheritance, here.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ok, I now see how this is a bad OOP design, and I now see how templates would be better here (that way one can write a linked list that takes an arbitrary type, where this type can be a class containing whatever you want, and, additionally, having overloaded operators, say for comparisons). Further thinking about what you said lead me to searching "inheritance vs. templates", which brought to two closed question on this site. One of the answers to the said closed question contained this link: http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/templateInheritance/  Seems like a worthwhile read.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the set_next and get_next methods in the Item class aren't 
overriden in the child NewItem class. As is you might try casting them to an Item object like so

```
i1->set_next((Item)i2);
NewItem* i3;
i3=(NewItem)(i1->get_next());
```

otherwise you need to override them

```
void set_next(NewItem* next) { next_=next; }
NewItem* get_next() const { return next_; }
```

Edit: I apologize I completely forgot about canonical form.

If you have pointers Inside of your class then you need to write a copy constructor.
this is because when in your main you say something like

```
Item a = b; // the copy constructor is called.
```

the class assumes you want a shallow copy, meaning it'll copy all member variables as is
including the pointer.
The problem is your NewItem object requires a different copy protocol from your Item class.

next you need to write a destructor where you delete any pointers in your classes member variables. in your program if you create an instance of Item inside a function, the program should de reference any pointers or you'll get a memory leak.

the destructor looks like a constructor with a tilde in front of it

```
~Item(){delete next_;}
```

Def check out cannonical form as it's imperative you understand it if your going to include
pointers in your classes.

also always remember to include ';' at the end of your class definition

ex:

```
class MyClass{
    ...
    ...
};  // ';' needs to go at the end of the class def
```

Comment: Do you mean casting to the pointer `Item*` as opposed to the object itself `Item`?  I considered that, but isn't that a tad dangerous?  I don't think overriding `set_next` and `get_next` methods wouldn't work in my case because you can't change the type of `next_` in the definition of the inherited class (I think...) and thus it would again require dangerous casting.

Comment: As this is tagged C++ I'd avoid C-style casting. Downcast using dynamic_cast instead.